# Elementary test software randomly appearing on my computer

Tags: software-uninstall

Today I was installing some things through terminal, such as Terminator terminal emulator and other various things, and the Elementary Test software randomly appeared on my computer. However, I do not recall once installing a virus-like thing or the app Elementary Config and Elementary Test (shown below).

[image: Elementary Config and Elementary Test apps in dash]

I have no clue what these do, and, as far as I know, they are not dependencies of any other applications.

I tried `apt list --installed` to see if it was installed from the terminal, and it isn't there. I also looked in my Ubuntu Software to see if it was installed, and it didn't show up. I also tried looking up the software on the internet and nothing showed up.

Just wondering if anyone knew about how to uninstall and how it got on my computer.

Any help would much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any of the Elementary OS PPAs enabled?

Comment: No I don't think so, I haven't used  anything to do with elementary OS, and none of the PPAs are enabled. I think that this program is something else that is standalone.

Comment: You can check the apt log `/var/log/apt/history.log` and that might shed some light.

Comment: Did you install the Enlightenment window manager ?

Comment: paste in terminal comand: sudo apt-get autoremove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed it by going to Settings → *Applications* → select *Elementary Test* then select *Open in Software* option in the top right. Finally *Remove*.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me